# Copying read-only sections into RAM

Tags: executable, ram, loader, readonly, sections

In Linux for example, when the loader loads an application or library into RAM, doesn't this make everything writable then?

For example, the `.text` area of an executable file should be read only. Will it no longer be read-only after it is loaded into RAM? This I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

1. When an application or library is loaded into RAM, the loader makes a copy of the file in RAM. The copy is writable, but the original file on disk is still read-only.
2. The .text area of an executable file is read-only because it contains the machine code for the program. Once the program is loaded into RAM, that machine code is executed directly from RAM, so it doesn't need to be read from the disk again.

Comment: The .text area before being copied into RAM is in read-only memory I guess? But then when copied to RAM it is no longer read only, so what is the point exactly? This is my confusion.

Comment: The machine code is read-only because it is executed directly by the CPU. If it were writable, then a malicious program could overwrite the machine code and cause the CPU to execute malicious code.

Comment: and what stops anyone from modifying the machine code when in RAM? In fact when we need to debug an application, the machine code must be modifyable as we must enter special instructions there for break-points.